# need help Debugging SSL handshake in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate

I have a very weird issue and looking for some tips. I have a certificate sent by client that I need to install so I can access HTTPS webservice. The certifcate has been installed, in both windows and Linux OS. using keytool command

```
keytool -import -alias ca -file somecert.cer -keystore cacerts –storepass changeit
```

when i deploy my application in windows tomcat I can communicate with HTTPS web server. However Linux tomcat gives me and error:

> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target   at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:236)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:194)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:216)

This means it couldn't find the certifcate. The certifcate is at java security cacerts. I have used `keytool -list` command and it is there.

I have no idea why it works in windows and not linux. I have tried setting the paramaters in the My servlet

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_14/jre/lib/security/cacerts"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

It still doesn't work.

My questions are:

1.Anyone has any idea why this isn't working, I have tired everything?

2.How do you enbale SSL debuging for tomcat.Ss setting `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all")` works ? For some reason I don't see any SSL debug Info in Catalina.out. Do I need to change anything else.What kind of debug info should i see.

Any help is greatly appericated I am out of ideas.

Comment: Did you configure SSL in Tomcat?  By default it isn't running.

Comment: is there a SSL client in tomcat, If there is i think it is running beacuse I have other HTTPS coomunication whihch work fine. only this one doesn't work. Could you help me check if it is running. Tomcat is a client here. I know for tomcat SSL server there are soem configuration

Comment: Could you clarify "I have a certificate sent by client"? Are you talking about client certificates? It sounds that your application (running within Tomcat) is a client that connects to another server (and thus has little to do with Tomcat itself). Is it the case?

Comment: Thats exactly what your saying Bruno. MY application (running within Tomcat) is a client that connects to another server (and thus has little to do with Tomcat itself). The applciation is a WAR depolyed on tomcat.tomcat uses JRE 5 which i have certifcate installed,

Comment: Any tips how Do i debug this? or activate SSL debug

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it is the webserver that is the issue and not a problem with the application not accepting the certificates?

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem you could try the following

Download SSLPoke.java

[SSLPoke.java](https://www.soft-gator.com/gfiles/SSLPoke.java)

Compile it:

```
javac SSLPoke.java
```

Once you compile code call SSLPoke as

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all SSLPoke [your https host] 443
```

In the output you will see where java is looking for cacerts.

Once you know the exact location use keytool to import your file to cacerts

```
keytool -import -alias [your https host] -keystore [the location returned]/cacerts -file [your.crt]
```

And that is all, restart tomcat and it must be working right.

Some times when you have lot of java versions on the same Linux machine even adding [your.crt] to the cacerts returned by debug does not work, if this is the case add [your.crt] to all cacerts on the Linux machine you can find them all with:

```
locate cacert
```

once the Linux machine return all the locations of cacerts for example:

```
/home/xuser/NetBeansProjects/porjectx/conf/cacerts
/opt/otherlocation/j2sdkee1.3.1/lib/security/cacerts.jks
/opt/icedtea-bin-6.1.12.7/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/icedtea-bin-6.1.13.5/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.4.1/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.7.0.76/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/sun-j2ee-1.3.1/lib/security/cacerts.jks
```

add [your.crt] to all of them with keytool and restart tomcat.

> If you dont have the file your.crt you can get it with command

`openssl s_client -connect [your https host]:443 < /dev/null`

> and copy from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE-----

I hope this help you

Comment: you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the certificate itself to see if there are any root certificates missing in the Certificate Path?

Also, keep in mind that if you're pointing to Java's built-in cacerts and you go to update Java, your cert(s) will get overwritten. I typically use an alternate keystore location for this reason.